# MongoDB options in connection string are being interpreted as the database name

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am trying to set the `maxPoolSize` via connection string in MongoDB following this piece of [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format). Here is my connection string:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName?maxPoolSize=200
```

However, instead of having the database **databaseName** with the **maxPoolSize** equals to 200, I'm getting a database called **databaseName?maxPoolSize=200**. This is, Mongo is getting everything (name + options) as the database name.

Some info:

- Mongo version: 3.2.10
- Connecting using Morphia 1.1.0

I will be happy to provide any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are doing

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(
"mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName?maxPoolSize=200");
```

then dont do that, instead do as following,

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(
new MongoClientURI(
"mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName?maxPoolSize=200"));
```

because you need to tell mongo that you are passing some options along the connection string.

if you think i misunderstood your question. please post the piece of code where you are trying to get a connection.

Comment: Both @satish and @Veeram answers are correct. I am giving @satish the correct answer because he replied earlier. That said, my problem was that my code parsed the database name from the connection string: `this.database = this.mongoClientUrl.split("/"); //and get the value of the last position` and executed `morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, this.database)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName?maxPoolSize=200");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "dbname");
```

Alternatively

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder options = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
//set your connection option here.
options.connectionsPerHost(200); //max pool size
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), options.build());
Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "dbname");
```